# How to reload tableview cell data using swift

Tags: swift

I have a tableview and two dropdown. When I am changing dropdown value cell data are repeating two times. I want to change my tableview cell data according to the dropdown changed value. When I will change the dropdown value the first data should be deleted and again it will be loaded according to the value changed in dropdown.

I had tried tableview.reloadData() in viewDidLoad() and also in my dropdown changed action method but it is not working.

```
select_activity.didSelect{(selectedText , index ,id) in
            self.select_subactivity.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            self.select_subactivity.text = ""
            self.getListOfSubactivity(activity_id: id)
            if(id == 2) {
                self.select_subactivity.didSelect{(selectedText, index, id) in
                    //self.Summary_tableView.isHidden = false
                    self.Summary_tableView.reloadData()
                    let user_id = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "user_id")!
                    let url = self.appDelegate.BaseUrl + "woodland/summary"
                    self.SummaryApi(url: url, userid: user_id, cph_id: cph_id!, subactivity_name: id)
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: call `reloadData` whenever drop down value changes, not in `ViewDidLoad()`, though `reloadData()` will work most effective and efficient way to do it would be to call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove all the elements from the array upon selection the value from the dropdown and then reload the table

Following Steps should be followed upon selecting a value from the dropDown:

1. Select the Value
2. Clear the array (array.removeAll()) to avoid duplication
3. Call the API
4. Reload the UITableView

Comment: But when I am changing my activity dropdown tableview was not removing although i have added the code array.removeAll() in select_activity.didselect.. method

Comment: Are you reloading the tableView after clearing the array?

Answer (score 0):

**viewDidLoad()** is called once after the view controller’s view has been loaded into memory. That's why your **tableview** is not reloading. you should try to call **tableview.reloadData()** where you are changing the dropdown value.